# Сохранение рисунков в pdf-файле: что нужно сделать, чтобы на одной странице сохранялось столько картинок, сколько помещается?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pdf, matplotlib

Добрый день. Есть несколько картинок, которые нужно сохранить в pdf-файле. Однако каждая картинка сохраняется на новой странице. Это не экономно. Что нужно сделать, чтобы на одной странице сохранялось столько картинок, сколько помещается? А следующая (которая не поместилась) сохранялась на второй странице и т.д. Спасибо!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf') 

# Рисуем первую картинку
arr = np.random.random_sample((10, 10))
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
seaborn.heatmap(arr)
plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')

# Рисуем вторую картинку
arr = np.random.random_sample((10, 10))
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
seaborn.heatmap(arr)
plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')

# Рисуем третью картинку
arr = np.random.random_sample((20, 20))
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
seaborn.heatmap(arr)
plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')

pp.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) можно контролировать как и сколько рисунков разместить на странице:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pp = PdfPages('c:/temp/multipage.pdf') 


# 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

# Рисуем первую картинку
sns.heatmap(np.random.random_sample((10, 10)), ax=axes[0,0])

# Рисуем вторую картинку
sns.heatmap(np.random.random_sample((10, 10)), ax=axes[0,1])

# Рисуем третью картинку
sns.heatmap(np.random.random_sample((10, 10)), ax=axes[1,0])

# Рисуем четвертую картинку
sns.heatmap(np.random.random_sample((10, 10)), ax=axes[1,1])

pp.savefig(fig)
pp.close()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]